# javafx app unknown publicher

Tags: java, javafx

i Developed a javafx app I self-signed the jar with my key pair and also I imported the  certificate to java keystore , and deployed it on the server.
every thing work  fine. but in the security dialog that prompt me to accept to run the app, is mentioned unknown publisher, How to change this in order  to display my identity.
I am worried about that because in the same dialog is mentioned also that in the next version this will not be permissible.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you'll have to purchase a digital certificate from a certification authority and sign the jar using that key. You can get one from companies like [Comodo](https://www.comodo.com/), [Verisign](https://www.verisign.com/), [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/) etc. There are also free certificate providers like [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/) as well.

More info on certificate authorities can be found in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

Comment: Thank for these infos. i solved my problem. i found out that i didn't add the certificate in the cacert.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, in the java contrôle panel.
Before,  my certificate was  not added to cacert.
now a new security dialog that publish my identity and it ask me if i trust this one, there is also a checkbox for not ask again about this publisher.